# Output column ID of duplicate MySQL Entry

Tags: mysql, duplicates, output

I have a table with the columns "ticket_id" and "subject".

I want to search the "subject" column for duplicates and then output the duplicates respective "ticket_id".

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT subject, COUNT(*) FROM ost_ticket__cdata GROUP BY subject HAVING COUNT(subject) > 1
```

Which works great, gives me a list and count of all the duplicate entries in the "subject" column, but how can I get their "ticket_id"?

The table is called "ost_ticket__cdata" and it contains two columns: "ticket_id" and "subject"

Answer (score 0):

Just use your query as a subquery to filter out the rows. For example:

```
select *
from ost_ticket__cdata
where subject in (
  SELECT subject FROM ost_ticket__cdata GROUP BY subject HAVING COUNT(subject) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS` you check for rows with the same `subject` but different `ticket_id`:

```
SELECT t.ticket_id
FROM ost_ticket__cdata t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM ost_ticket__cdata
  WHERE ticket_id <> t.ticket_id AND subject = t.subject
)
ORDER BY t.ticket_id
```

Comment: Thanks man this is great! Is there a way to have it output only the t.ticket_id? I was able to get it to output to a file. I changed it to `ORDER BY t.ticket_id` but still gives me the t.subject as well. Regardless, this gives me what I needed. Next I will be building this into a php script to remove the duplicates. Much appreciated.